# How can I combine the results of different variables into one variable?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, controller

I have following four variables in my controller index action which are retrieving data from different models as follows:

```
@forum = Forum.where(:user_id => @users.collect(&:user_id)).all
@poll=Poll.where(:created_by => @users.collect(&:user_id)).all
@article = Article.where(:user_id => @users.collect(&:user_id)).all
@jobpost = Jobplacement.where(:user_id => @users.collect(&:user_id)).all
```

I want to join all these variables' data into a single variable `@post`. How can I do this?

Comment: Why do you want to store different objects in single variable?

Comment: sounder..I want to show all these variable data onto single page according to date and time on which they are created.So i thought i will store it in a single variable and then do " @post.reverse.each do " to show posts in the order of datetime

Answer (score 2):

It is not good to have different type of objects in single collection.
But as you asked try

```
@post = [@forum,@forum,@article,@jobpost].flatten
```

Update:
I wrote this answer when I was a newbie in Ruby. When I look this answer I can not control my smile. The purpose of the flatten is to make a single array from the nested arrays. The answer does not relate to the question. But I am surprised about the upvotes :)

Comment: Go to your rails console and try [[1,2],[3,4]].flatten then see what happens

Comment: This is beautiful, even if it's technically a 'no no'.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
conditions = { :user_id => @users }  # assuming primary_key is set correctly
                                     # in the User model
@post = Forum.where( conditions ).all   +
        Poll.where( conditions ).all    +
        Article.where( conditions ).all +
        Jobplacement.where( conditions ).all
```

Or if you want to get fancy:

```
models = [ Forum, Poll, Article, Jobplacement ]

@post  = models.reduce [] do |records, model|
  records.push *model.where( :user_id => @users ).all
end
```

**Note:** `.all` might be unnecessary in both cases since it's usually called automatically by Rails when necessary, but I'm not certain.

Answer (score 0):

Put them in a hash:

```
@post = Hash.new
@post['forum']   = Forum.where(:user_id => @users.collect(&:user_id)).all
@post['poll']    = Poll.where(:created_by => @users.collect(&:user_id)).all
@post['article'] = Article.where(:user_id => @users.collect(&:user_id)).all
@post['job_placement'] = Jobplacement.where(:user_id => @users.collect(&:user_id)).all
```

They are not *joined*, but they are in one single variable. You can access them whenever you want, and do with them whatever you want.

Comment: @post['forum'],@post['poll'], @post['article'],@post['job_placement'] what these means.

Comment: `@post['forum']` means the key `forum` of the hash `@post`. Think of a hash as an associative array (in PHP for example). I recommend you learning some Ruby basics, and checking the documentation from time to time. :)

Answer (score 0):

I think you need like view model concept. Create a simple model class without inherit from `ActiveRecord::Base` and add all objects as attributes in the new class and initialize that.

```
class Post 
   attr_accessor :forum, :poll, :article, :jobpost
   def initialize(forum,poll,article,jobpost)
      @forum = forum
      @poll = poll
      @article = article
      @jobpost = jobpost
   end
end
```

In the controller action add the following;

```
@post = Post.new(@forum,@poll,@article,@jobpost)
```